# Unity encryption BIS compliant?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, encryption, export

I only use serialize fields in game to conceal answers in quizzes/jokes/riddles and other things that need to be hidden from users. I am aware that Unity has a lot going on under the hood. Is Unity using encryption, and what is used for serialize fields? Are these methods BIS compliant?

I found a lot about IOS and the app store, but I am building to Google Play for Android devices.

Comment: Beware: questions like yours historically attract a lot of bad answers with bad or misleading information.

Comment: I am aware of that. I was just hoping to get info from other peoples' experiences.

Comment: I did find this.https://forum.unity.com/threads/us-export-compliance-encryption.389208/